# Как передать колекцию в Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle

Я создал тип данных **CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numbersID AS TABLE OF number;** и есть процедура которая принимаят эту тип данных(numbersID) как параметр, как вызвать процедуру в ручную и протестировать ?

```
PROCEDURE GET_ACCOUNTS(ACCOUNT_ID IN numbersID, O_RESULT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN O_RESULT FOR
      SELECT DEX.TID ID, DEX.IBAN, DEX.CURRENCY,
              T.NAME
      FROM RSBANK.DACCOUNT_DBT T
      LEFT JOIN RSF.EXTEND DEX
           ON DEX.ACCOUNT = T.ACCOUNT
      WHERE T.ACCOUNTID IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(ACCOUNT_ID));
  END;
```

Comment: Что используете для доступа к БД?

Comment: @SwaD C#, Dapper

Comment: Не из приложения, а как вы ходите в саму БД Oracle, что бы там просто поселектить что то, теже типы и процедуры как создавали, при помощи какого инструмента? Toad, PL/SQL Developer, SQL developer... может еще что

Comment: @SwaD PL/SQL Developer

Comment: На процедуре правую кнопку мыши -> test. В окне появится процедура. Там же объявление переменной. После begin пишите `ACCOUNT_ID := numbersID(12, 34, 56);` и выполняете. Внутрь процедуры(правда на скомпилить будет), можете напихать dbms_output.

Comment: @SwaD да, все работает , значит проблема на стороне приложения